# Retrieve data and open view controller from FCM notification data IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I send this data to my android device it works correctly and an activity opens corresponding to the 'click_action'. I am also able to collect the data such as 'title' and 'price' and put them into strings.

However with iOS I can't figure out how to collect the data from the notification and then open a certain view controller when the notification is clicked.

[Notification Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGXwc.png)

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Using `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is the current way of handling touch events.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
...
if let userInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] {
  NSLog("[RemoteNotification] applicationState: \(applicationStateString) didFinishLaunchingWithOptions for iOS9: \(userInfo)")
  //TODO: Handle background notification
}
return true
  }
```

> Notes:
>   NO notification will appear on device’s notification center when receiving remote notification in active state. You may need to present your notification in your own way.
>   If you need to present or push view controllers based on the content of notification. You need to save the content of notification and handle it until UIs are all ready.

Courtesy of [FCM on Swift 3](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-remote-notification-with-firebase-tutorial-118acd3ebce1)

Comment: But how do I get the data from the notification itself.

Comment: More specific. Please

Comment: What im trying to do is take the data from the notification in the screenshot such as 'price' and then from that do a action accordingly.

Comment: Read the data using the userInfo variable?

Comment: Oh so like this for string 'price':   NSLog("[RemoteNotification] applicationState: \(applicationStateString) didFinishLaunchingWithOptions for iOS9: \(price)")